# XML fetching using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, send

This code wont execute. I think there is something wrong with the `xhttp.send()` function. Because the `alert` function before it executes but the `alert` function after it doesn't execute:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PAGE OUTPUT</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function aa()
    {   
        var xhttp;
        alert("hi welcome"); 
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            alert("hi");
        }
        else
        {
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET","vehicle.xml",false);
        alert("OPEN EXECUTED");
        xhttp.send();
        alert("SEND EXECUTED");
        xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
        alert("HI I HAVE REACHED OVER HERE");
        var vehicle=xmlDoc.documentElement;
        var car=vehicle.firstChild.nodeValue;
        var price=car.firstChild.nodeValue;
        alert(price);
    }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
<center><input type="submit" onclick="aa()"></center>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you trying this page as a file in local filesystem? That causes a cross-site XHR, and most browsers would forbid it.

Comment: both the file are in the same folder ...i dont think that should be a problem

Comment: browsers will fail to send any XHR if you visiting local files. See my answer below please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better to check if the URL is like **file:///path/to/file** the browser will fail to send any XHR from the page, for security reasons (nowadays that seems unreasonable).

You should launch a server for this case, and visit that page in **http://localhost/path/to/file**. The easiest way I know is to launch a [Python](http://python.org/) SimpleHTTPServer. You might install python yourself if you are using MS Windows, or it will be available in Mac/any Linux distributions. Then follow these steps

- launch a terminal (on MS Windows it's called a command line prompt, using Win+R then type `cmd` to launch one)
- `cd` to the path where the files locate
- execute `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
- visit `http://localhost:8000/html_file` in your browser
- click on that button as usual

Now you will see those `alert`s. Additionally, you might have to change `xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML` to `xmlDoc = xhttp.responseText` if necessary.

Then try [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), that's much easier for ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the submit button click

```
onclick="aa(); return false;"
```

Comment: i m trying to fetch some value from the xml file vehicle.xml but the statement xhttp.send() isnt executing i think ...both the file(ie vehicle.xml and this file are in the same folder )